# Apache htaccess if directive does not recognize AND

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header

I have .htaccess code like this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /page=edit_page/ && %{REQUEST_METHOD} =~ /POST/">
         Header set X-XSS-Protection "0"
    </If>
</IfModule>
```

But it is not working.

I am trying to set the header if the page is edit_page and has post data in it.

Can anyone tell me why or tell me a better way to do this?

Comment: What is URL you are using to test this?

Comment: https://www.sitename.com/?page=edit_page&page_name=Test

Comment: I tested with `curl -i -d '' 'http://localhost/?page=edit_page&page_name=Test'` and got `X-XSS-Protection: 0` in headers.